# C++ destructor called before lifetime of scope

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, stack, heap-memory

I have a question about triggering a destructor for an object prematurely. I have an dynamically allocated array of pointers to dynamically allocated Word objects. The name of the array is words_. words_ is a class attribute of another class called Dictionary.

In my Dictionary class, I have a function where I access each Word object and call a member function of the Word class.

The below code triggers the destructor prematurely:

```
Word *curr_word_ptr = words_[idx]; // This line is okay, doesn't trigger destructor
Word curr_word = *curr_word_ptr; // This line triggers the destructor prematurely
curr_word.callMemberFunc();
```

Because of the second line, as soon as the scope of the function ends, the destructor is called.

But if I access it through the array indices alone:

```
*(words_[idx]).callMemberFunc(); // The desctructor is not called prematurely
```

Is the problem because I have a stack variable (not even a stack pointer variable) accessing a dynamically allocated object? Thus, when the scope of the function ends, both the stack variable (curr_word) and the dynamically allocated stack object gets destroyed?

Thank you.

Comment: Would you like to see the Word class? Or how the words_ array is dynamically allocated? Or the Dictionary function?

Comment: `Word curr_word` creates an instance of `Word` in with automatic storage duration, which is destructed when the scope in which `curr_word` is created ends. Why do you expect anything else?

Comment: @PIprog3592 Yes, basically all relevatnt code, or even better a true [mre], unless the current answer solves your problem. I wasn't sure what destructor you meant, but it seems to be clear now?

Comment: The c++ specification does not talk about `stack` and `heap` but about storage duration and lifetime. If the tutorial or book you use for learning only talks about stack and heap, and not in combination with storage duration, then you probably should consider choosing a different book/tutorial.

Comment: @t.niese Just curious, what is incorrect about refering to stack and heap in c++? Does it not work that way? Or is it more complex than stack and heap?

Comment: @PIprog3592 stack and heap are a way how an implementation can follow the rules of the specification. But from the perspective of lifetime it is better to learn it the way how the specification defines the lifetime of objects. Stack and heap can - to a certain degree - be used to illustrate certain things, but it is just not how it is defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Word curr_word = *curr_word_ptr;` defines a local `Word`, that only lives in the local scope, your function. When the function exits, it is destroyed. Note it is a copy of the initial `Word` that is destroyed, not the original.

If you want handy syntax so you don't have to dereference all over, or make a copy, use a reference:

```
Word &word = *curr_word_ptr;
```

This is the syntactic sugar C++ provides to refer to an object without pointers (directly). Note though, any changes made to `word` will affect your original word as well in this case.

The problem is even worse if your `Word`s contains dynamically allocated memory. Assuming you use the default copy constructor, the addresses will be copied. As such, destruction of a local `Word` will free memory still referenced by the original `Word`, causing a crash when next accessed.

Comment: So only the copy of the initial Word is destroyed? That's weird, because it called the destructor for the dynamically allocated Word object in the array itself, which crashed the program when another function tried to access the missing object in the array.

Comment: @PIprog3592 I doubt that. Likely, the word contains itself pointers references. As such, when copied, you make a shallow copy - so when the local word is destroyed, it frees (possibly) these pointers. The original is not destroyed, but will still reference free memory (and crash). Without a full example I can't know for sure, but this seems likely.

Comment: @PIprog3592 If you want to ask a separate question on that, I think that would be fine (assuming you need a longer clarification than my comment). You would need to provide a fuller example.

Comment: The Word class itself contained a dynamically allocated array of c strings. When I saw the destructor being called, it deleted the array of c strings for the Word object. Is that the culprit?

Comment: @PIprog3592 You've got it. The original is not destroyed, but the local destructor frees the array. Next time your original word accesses this - kaboom.

Comment: @PIprog3592 then you most certainly did not follow the [rules of zero/three/five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: t.niese is correct, google that - it's an important concept, especially when dealing with dynamic memory.

Comment: @kabanus How is the original Word object not being destroyed, but yet the local destructor frees the array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three?rq=1 is probably relevant

Comment: @PIprog3592 If two things point to cell 0x10 in memory, then when one frees it, the other thing still points there (you made no changes to that, a pointer is just a number). Please ask a separate question on this matter if it is unclear, this comment thread is too long.

Comment: @PIprog3592 Because you shallow copied the array to the local object. As already said you are not following the rule of three. This code is not going to work until you understand that concept and correct your `Word` class.

Comment: @kabanus Last question. I understand how the local Word object triggers the destructor now. However, let's say I just stick to the first line of the code by using the pointer curr_word_ptr. If I do curr_word_ptr->word(), this works also. By using the pointer, we are accessing the Word object in the heap, and so we are not making a local copy of the object itself? Correct?

Comment: @PIprog3592 Correct. Using a reference as in my example also works (or a local **pointer**, that would be the same as a reference except you would use `->` everywhere instead of `.`).

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
Word curr_word = *curr_word_ptr;
```

creates on stack copy of the object and that copy gets destroyed.

Most probably you class has missing a logic and you need define copy constructor to prevent crashes or disable copy constructor so you can create copy by mistake like here.

```cpp
*(words_[idx]).callMemberFunc();
```

Invokes method directly on object pointed by object stored in array. Copy is not created.

Other way you can write this line:

```cpp
words_[idx]->callMemberFunc();
```

I see also a problem since you are using raw pointers. Since c++11 this approach is considered bad practice. Learn to use `std::uniqie_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.

Also use `std::vector` instead regular C-array